# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gogogo.chatMessage' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, web

I'm making a web project, and after I done it locally I upload to server(centos7), but when I go to the main page , the log return this error.

The weird thing is everything works good on my laptop(Mac), but when I open it through server. The spring-boot log told that can't find two tables. all others tables seem ok. and homepage do get data from db.From now I can't find solution from internet.and I checked the db in server, both tables are exist.(there is no data inside them currently.)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orderItem")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "handler","hibernateLazyInitializer" })
public class OrderItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pid")

private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="oid")
private Order order;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="uid")
private User user;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="sid")
private User seller;


public List<Request> getRequests() {
    return requests;
}

public void setRequests(List<Request> requests) {
    this.requests = requests;
}

@Transient
private List<Request> requests;

private int status;
private int price;
private Date createDate;
private int way;
private int number;
```

///////////////////////////////////////
 +----------------------+
 | Tables_in_gogogo 
 +----------------------+
 | address              |
 | category             |
 | chatmessage          |
 | order_               |
 | orderitem            |
 | product              |
 | productimage         |
 | property             |
 | propertyvalue        |
 | request              |
 | review               |
 | user                 |
 | userimage            |
 | wishlist             |
 +----------------------+
//////////////////////////////

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/gogogo?       
useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDate
timeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicalstrategy=
org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    at  org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 65 more
```

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gogogo.orderItem' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        ... 96 more

I have wasted a lot of time on this bug.

Comment: Table names are case sensitive in MySQL. Correct your table name to "orderitem" in the entity class and try again. And same with "chatmessage" table.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm upload the jar to server and trying. but if you are correct. why there is no error when its on my laptop?

Comment: It depends on the case sensitivity of underlying operating system. And your macOS is exceptional. Read this link for more details : [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: @Gopi, thank you very much! finally solved it.

Comment: Great. Can you up vote my answer!

Comment: @Gopi, how to vote the comment?

Comment: Seems you need to have reputation 15 to vote on comments. I'll write the solution again and you can vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names are case sensitive in MySQL. Correct your table name to "orderitem" in the entity class and try again. And same with "chatmessage" table.